# How do I get the status of an Ajax call in Bacon.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript, bacon.js

jQuery's Ajax handler returns an array of arguments when its promise resolves, and the initial tuple is `([data], "status")`.  I've found that when I use `Bacon.fromPromise`, all I get back is the data.  How would I get the status of the transaction, and how would I handle any actual failures from jQuery?

What I'm trying to do is download two bundles of data, of the same schema, from two different URLs and concatenate them.  I think I've got the concatenation figured out, but the error handling is driving me nuts.  Here's what I'm trying:

```
requestData = Bacon.fromPromise $.get @users_stories
requestRefs = Bacon.fromPromise $.get @reference_stories

success = (d, s) -> s == "success"
fetchFailure = requestData.map(success).not()
    .merge(requestRefs.map(success).not())
fetchFailure.onValue => alert "Failed to download"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that, instead of looking for the status text, you should be using the error callback of the stream objects.  [For example](http://jsfiddle.net/H7R8h/11/), to merge the requests and handle any errors (JS, sorry, I'm not fluent with Coffee Script):

```
requestData.merge(requestRefs).onError(function(e) {
    alert("Failed to download: " + e.responseText);
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the `mapError` function to merge the error events into the observable stream:

```
requestData.merge(requestRefs).mapError(function(e) {
    return e.statusText;
}).onValue(function(next) {
    if (next.feed) {
        // handle feed
    } else {
        alert("Error: " + next);
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H7R8h/12/)

**Edit**

You can see from the [fromPromise source](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/blob/master/dist/Bacon.js) that any reference to the "data" object is swallowed up.  All `fromPromise` does with the promise you give it is to bind the observable's handler to the `promise.then`'s "resolved" and "rejected" callbacks:

```
Bacon.fromPromise = function(promise, abort) {
    return Bacon.fromBinder(function(handler) {
      promise.then(handler, function(e) {
        return handler(new Error(e));
      });
      return function() {
        if (abort) {
          return typeof promise.abort === "function" ? promise.abort() : void 0;
        }
      };
    }, function(value) {
      return [value, end()];
    });
  };
```

In other words, the only way you can get access to the status text would be to save a reference to the promise objects.  But you don't need to do that -- all you need is to handle Bacon's `observable.onError`.

Comment: Fair enough.  It just doesn't seem very, um, bacony, to depend on Bacon's error handling, rather than handling the array of possible error conditions on my own.